# How to set buttons in left and right(leading/trailing) in navigation bar swift ui?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uinavigationbar

I want to set one button in **left(leading)** of **navigation bar** and one button in **right(trailing)** of navigation bar in swift ui.
Please help me to do it.

```
.navigationBarItems(leading:
  HStack {
   Button("About") {
    print("About tapped!")
   }
  }
 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following modifier

```
.navigationBarItems(leading:
   Button("About") {
    print("About tapped!")
   },
 trailing: 
   Button("Settings") {
    print("Settings tapped!")
   }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for set multiple buttons:

```
.navigationBarItems(
   leading:
     HStack {
       Button("About") {
         print("About tapped!")
       }
       Button("Call") {
         print("Call tapped!")
       }
     },

   trailing:
     HStack {
       Button("Settings") {
         print("Settings tapped!")
       }
       Button("Contacts") {
         print("Contacts tapped!")
       }           
     }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

navigationBarItems is deprecated. Hence below code will work.

```
.toolbar {
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement:.navigationBarTrailing) {
                        HStack{
                            Button("Add"){
                                saveDetails()
                                dismiss()
                            }
                        }
                       
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button("Cancel"){
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
```

In this Add button will be shown as right button and cancel as left.